# C++ class member template function to insert an obj into a member std::vector

Tags: class, templates, c++11, vector

How do I make a template function that can insert any inherited class from a game obj abstract class into a known type std vector?

Here is some code to make sense of it, note that it should not be able compile:

```
enum GAMEOBJ_TYPE {
  WIRE = 'w',
  GATE = 'g',
};

std::vector<Wire*> wires;
std::vector<Gate*> gates;

template <typename T>
void SortAndInsertIntoVector (T *obj, GAMEOBJ_TYPE type ) {
  switch (type) {
    case WIRE:
    wires.push_back(obj);
    break;

    case GATE:
    gates.push_back(obj);
    break;
  }
}
```

From what I know the compiler generates code and replaces T with the types that the compiler finds at each call to this template function to generate a function template of each type.
Hence we would get 2 new functions as this:

```
void SortAndInsertIntoVector_CompilerMangled_Wire (Wire *obj, GAMEOBJ_TYPE type ) {
  switch (type) {
    case WIRE:
    wires.push_back(obj);
    break;

    case GATE:
    gates.push_back(obj);
    break;
  }
}

void SortAndInsertIntoVector_CompilerMangled_Gate (Gate *obj, GAMEOBJ_TYPE type ) {
  switch (type) {
    case WIRE:
    wires.push_back(obj);
    break;

    case GATE:
    gates.push_back(obj);
    break;
  }
}
```

Hence we would get the compiler error during this generation as the type Wire cannot be inserted into a vector of gates and vice versa.

Is there a better way to code this so that I can insert the obj into the right vector apart from manually overloading the function. (Imagine if I had 20 types of game objs)

Also is there a better optimization that I could do to not have the ENUM switch case in the function and let the compiler discern which vector is appropriate to use? (This might be impossible, but I heard of compile time computations which can generate code such as this)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe still use function call overloading, without the templating, mostly because as you correctly deduce: it doesn't add anything here:

```
void SortAndInsertIntoVector (Wire* obj) {
   wires.push_back(obj);
}

void SortAndInsertIntoVector (Gates* obj) {
   gates.push_back(obj);
}
```

This eliminates the need for the ENUM and will provide type safety and you can use the same function call for your (limited, I hope) number of data types.

EDIT: this is one way how you could do it with templates though, if you resign to not naming the destination vectors explicitly by a name. In the suggestion below you can always access the stored objects via e.g. `gameobs<Wire*>::theObjects`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct gameobjs {
    static vector<T> theObjects;
};
template <typename T>
vector<T> gameobjs<T>::theObjects;

template <typename T>
void SortAndInsertIntoVector(T* obj) {
    gameobjs<T*>::theObjects.push_back( obj );
}

int main( void ) {
    SortAndInsertIntoVector((int*)0);
    SortAndInsertIntoVector((float*)0);

    cout << "Number of ints:   " << gameobjs<int*>::theObjects.size() << endl;
    cout << "Number of floats: " << gameobjs<float*>::theObjects.size() << endl;
    cout << "Number of chars:  " << gameobjs<char*>::theObjects.size() << endl;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Number of ints:   1
Number of floats: 1
Number of chars:  0
```

Comment: Hey this seems to be the way to go! Thanks!

However I encountered a minor hiccup when trying to encapsulate the variables and methods into a class. Mainly because the static keyword is allocating memory that is being shared by all instances of the class type. Simply removing the static keyword and refactoring was all it took.

Comment: Actually, the static is necessary. Otherwise each `gameobs<Type*>::theObjects` will reference a different instance of the vector-of-objectpointers. Compare with your original design: the `wires` and `gates` variables are global variables (for a reason!). The "static" declaration makes sure that all uses of `gameobjs<Type*>::theObjects` reference the same vector instance.